# AWS EMR terminated with validation error - security group error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr, aws-security-group

When we try launch AWS EMR in Mumbai region, it gets terminated in 5-6 seconds with the following validation error.

"Terminated with errors The EC2 Security Groups [sg-XXXXXXXXXX] contain one or more ingress rules to ports other than [22] which allow public access."

These are default security groups created for AWS EMR in Mumbai region. How to overcome this?

Comment: See if this helps https://www.cloudconformity.com/knowledge-base/aws/EC2/security-group-ingress-any.html

Comment: The issue arose because of a new security feature of EMR clusters to prevent customers from mistakenly exposing them to the internet. This is solved by AWS

Comment: @Kavyashree Can you please share how this issue was resolved by AWS?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're not blocking the ports yore using (from public nets). You can go to `Amazon EMR`, then `Block public access` and add the ports you want to access from public network in `Exceptions` (or just disabling the option `Block public access`).

[image: Final cluster's Block public access settings]

Comment: This was so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue and resolved it by doing the below.

Before creating your EMR cluster go to our Security Groups( for ElasticMapReduce-master and ElasticMapReduce-slave) and delete all the inbound rules other than for SSH(Port 22).This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Read the message carefully: this occurs if your security group allows public access to a port or port range other than 22 (ssh), for example having an inbound rule that allows access from any IP with 0.0.0.0. This is a security risk and you should restrict access to known static IPs, such as "My IP" in "Source" dropdown.

See this document for more information https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/prisma/prisma-cloud/prisma-cloud-policy-reference/configuration-policies/configuration-policies-build-phase/amazon-web-services-configuration-policies/policy_617b9138-584b-4e8e-ad15-7fbabafbed1a.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console#security-group-rules